# Execute python script, get its print and logging output and assert unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, logging, python-unittest

**Edit:** Thanks @eemz for the idea to redesign the structure and use `from unittest.mock import patch`, but the problem persists.

So I just recently stumbled into unittest and I have a program which I normally start like this `python run.py -config /path/to/config.file -y`. I wanted to write a simple test in a separate `test.py` file: Execute the script, pass the mentioned arguments and get all of its output. I pass a prepared config file which is missing certain things, so the `run.py` will break and exactly log this error using `logging.error`: "xyz was missing in Config file!" (see example below). I'll get a few words from `print()` and then the `logging` instance kicks in and handles from there on. How do I get its output so I can check it? Feel free to rewrite this, as I'm still learning, please bear with me.

Simplified example:

`run.py`

```py
import logging

def run(args):
  < args.config = /path/to/config.file >
  cnfg = Config(args.config)

  cnfg.logger.info("Let's start with the rest of the code!") # This is NOT in 'output' of the unittest
  < code >

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("Welcome! Starting execution.") # This is in 'output' of the unittest
  < code to parse arguments 'args' >
  run(args)
```

`Config.py`

```py
import logging

class Config:
  def __init__(self):
    print("Creating logging instance, hold on ...") # This is in 'output' of the unittest
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    logger.info("Logging activated, let's go!") # This is NOT in 'output' of the unittest
    self.logger = logger

    if xyz not in config:
      self.logger.error("xyz was missing in Config file!") # This is NOT in 'output' of the unittest
      exit(1)
```

`test.py`

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestConfigs(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_xyz(self):
        with patch('sys.stdout', new=StringIO()) as capture:
            with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
                run("/p/to/f/missing/xyz/f", "", False, True)
        output = capture.getvalue().strip()

        self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 1)
        # Following is working, because the print messages are in output
        self.assertTrue("Welcome! Starting execution." in output)
        # Following is NOT working, because the logging messages are not in output
        self.assertTrue("xyz was missing in Config file!" in output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Not directly relevant, but pytest might be worth looking into because it's a superset of unittest and gives better stack traces on error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up instantiating the logger of the main program with a specific name, so I could get the logger in the `test.py` again and assert that the logger was called with a specific text. I didn't know that I could just get the logger by using logging.getLogger("name") with the same name. Simplified example:

`test.py`

```py
import unittest
from run import run
from unittest.mock import patch

main_logger = logging.getLogger("main_tool")

class TestConfigs(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_xyz(self):
        with patch('sys.stdout', new=StringIO()) as capture, \
             self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm, \
             patch.object(main_logger , "info") as mock_log1, \
             patch.object(main_logger , "error") as mock_log2:
                run("/path/to/file/missing/xyz.file")
        output = capture.getvalue().strip()

        self.assertTrue("Creating logging instance, hold on ..." in output)
        mock_log1.assert_called_once_with("Logging activated, let's go!")
        mock_log2.assert_called_once_with("xyz was missing in Config file!")
        self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

`run.py`

```py
def run(path: str):
  cnfg = Config(path)
  < code >

if __name__ == "__main__":
  < code to parse arguments 'args' >
  path = args.file_path
  run(path)
```

`Config.py`

```py
import logging

class Config:
  def __init__(self, path: str):
    print("Creating logging instance, hold on ...")
    logger = logging.getLogger("main_tool")
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    logger.info("Logging activated, let's go!")
    self.logger = logger

    # Load file, simplified
    config = load(path)

    if xyz not in config:
      self.logger.error("xyz was missing in Config file!")
      exit(1)
```

This method seems to be very complicated and I got to this point by reading through a lot of other posts and the docs. Maybe some one knows a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure run.py like this:

```
import logging

def main():
  print("Welcome! Starting execution.")
  Etc etc

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Then you can call the function run.main() in your unit test rather than forking a subprocess.

```
from io import StringIO
from unittest.mock import patch
import sys

import run

class etc etc
  def test_run etc etc:
    with patch('sys.stdout', new=StringIO()) as capture:
      sys.argv = [‘run.py’, ‘-flag’, ‘-flag’, ‘-flag’]
      run.main()
      output = capture.getvalue().strip()
    assert output == <whatever you expect it to be>
```

If you’re new to unit testing then you might not have seen mocks before. Effectively I am replacing stdout with a fake one to capture everything that gets sent there, so that I can pull it out later into the variable output.

In fact a second patch around sys.argv would be even better because what I’m doing here, an assignment to the real argv, will actually change it which will affect subsequent tests in the same file.

Comment: That is indeed nice and works nicely so far. However, I'm still not able to get the output of the logging instance. `output` will contain what `run.py` is writing via `print()` but not what is written with `logger.x()`. I'll will update my question with further information, maybe there will be the problem somewhere.